# What is vedAdi?

Tags: vedas, vedanta

It is believed by the vedantins that the upanishad are called as veda-anta because they are the concluding part of the vedas.

So my question is

If there is something called as vedanta then what is

Veda-aadi

And

Veda-Madhya etc?

Are there any references for the same?

Comment: Vedanta is not end of Veda. It is end of Knowledge (although veda means knoweldge). Vedanta helps to get AtmaJnana which leads to BrahmaJnana and thus ends the knowledge.

Comment: @TheDestroyer please re read the question. I.said it's believed to be the concluding portion of vedas.if vedanta.means jnanam then it should be called as beginning of jnanam or end of ignorance.

Comment: This won't be answered because there's nothing called VedAdi :D

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure whether there exists a seperate portion called vedAdi or Veda Madhya in Vedas or not. However there is a word called 'vedAdi' in Taittariya Aranyaka of YajurVeda in the sense as beginning of Vedas:

> **यो वेदादौ स्वर प्रोक्तो** वेदान्ते च प्रतिष्ठित ।
>   तस्य प्रकृतिलीनस्य यः परस्सः महेश्वर ।। (YajurVeda Taiitariya Aranyaka 10.12.3)
>   
>   He who is spoken in the beginning of the Vedas (vedAdi) and who is also established in end portion of Vedas (vedAnte), On whom the whole Prakirti merges finally, He is Lord Maheswara.

Comment: if i am not wrong this says that vedaadi and vedaanta is nothing but same thing. I.e pranava. So upanishads separately being vedanta is not mentioned it vedas but is views of later acharyas.

Comment: This also hints that vedadi and vedanta.are not different and hence vedas should be taken as a.whole and not in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Though literally "VedAnta" means "End of Veda", it should be interpreted as **Beyond Veda**. Because "end" is also a part of Vedas.

*VedAnta* is an umbrella term for various philosophies and is not limited to Upanishada-s. Hence, I will concentrate on "VedAnta" in general.
Bhagavad Gita is also considered as a "VedAnta", because it doesn't talk about worldly matters, like 'what or what not - to do'. Rather it discusses the final destination, which is beyond every worlds (*loka*-s).

Here is that verse, which supports why, "VedAnta = Beyond Veda":

> BG 2.45 - **Veda-s are subjected to only 3 modes** of material nature (*Sattva, Rajas, Tamas*); O Arjuna, become free of these 3 modes, free of duality, ever situated in "constant-ness"; free of gaining support [and] self sustained.

The lord suggests Arjuna to be beyond traditional Veda-s viz. *VedAnta*. And attain the state of non-duality, viz. *Advaita*.
<sub>[Note: There is no mention in Gita, if Krishna referred *Purva/Uttara MimAnsa* of Vedas.]</sub>

Comment: Lol if it's beyond veda.then it's not a part of veda isn't it?.so technically vedanta is not veda. I am ok to accept that vedanta is not veda. But something else

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, yes you understood it correct. "VedAnta" cannot be part of "Veda". The proof is Bhagavad Gita, which discusses on liberation. While Veda-s primarily discuss on 3 modes (*Sattva, Rajas, Tamas*). Now some people say that, Veda also discuss on liberation. My view here is that, it might have been added later for the sake completeness. Because 3 modes and liberation can't be taught in a same breathe. It's like teaching about marriage & divorce in the same breathe. :-) During Gita, Krishna just describes those 3 modes, but never prefers anyone mode over the other.

Comment: I think u are mistaken here. BG has nothing to do with Vedanta. Vedanta means Upanishad. OP is asking about that.

Comment: I first time saw "Beyond Veda"! It's Vedanta, not Vedatita. Have you referred English translation by Gambhirananda? Also Adi Shankaracharya's Bhashya says "For those who....."

Comment: @Pandya, the literal meaning is indeed "End of Veda", but it should be interpreted as "beyond Veda". As discussed in 2.45, Vedas discuss mainly about 3 modes. While Vedanta based philosophy Gita has several references of "beyond 3 modes". Yes I refer Gambhirananda's translation by default. In this case it's slightly mistaken about 'Nitya + Satva + Stha" instead of correct 'Nitya + Sat + Avastha'.

Comment: @iammilind please prove that vedas are traigunya vishaya ?

Comment: @iammilind it could be an interpolation because then vedas would.not hold ultimate authority

Comment: @iammilind That Vedanta is a philosophy. It's one of the Shad Darsanas. Here OP means Upanishad only by Vedanta.

Comment: @Rickross, if you refer the wiki article then Vedanta is not a single entity to be termed as 'philosophy', but rather a collective term for various philosophies: *"It does not stand for one comprehensive or unifying doctrine. Rather it is an umbrella term for many sub-traditions, ... called the Prasthanatrayi. The Prasthanatrayi is a collective term for the Principal Upanishads, the Brahma Sutras and the Bhagavad Gita."* Usually Gita has brief essence of detailed Upanishada-a.. Since the Qn is not tagged for Upanishada, I was Ok to present another perspective, which is more casual.