# Do Vedas support Advaitic Philosophy?

Tags: vedas, advaita

Which Verses in VedaSamhitas,Brahmanas,Aryanyakas) speak of ultimate reality as Brahman and knowing Brahman alone is purpose of life and by realizing thus-the world becomes illusion ?

Comment: Here is a similar question -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23512/vedas-and-their-philosophy/23525

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rickross ji  but still missing concept of Maya and world as Illusion in Vedas.

Comment: Vedas never supported advaita its only interpertation of shankara that did it. that is why lot of contradiction in the interpretation.. its all there to confuse those who want to know real philosophy..

Comment: Whether Vedas support Advaita or not is a different question but the main Upanishads clearly support Advaita. It is therefore nearly an impossible task to interpret Upanishads from Dvaita perspective. Advaita is the most natural conclusion of the Upanishads @PrasannaR

Comment: Lovely @Rickross Ji Sahasra Pranam _/ | \_

Comment: You mean Mandukya upanishad supports Advaita..dwsuparana is biggest contradiction see my comments top panday in your reference link except Mahavakyas that picked incorrectly qutoed out of context.. nothing says about advaita.. serveral things still unresolved in advaita right from creating why the single entity showed as many different things.. in the first place.. this question is unresolvable in advaita..@Rickross

Comment: @Rickross Ji! Is Maya really Illusion according to Upanishads?

Comment: Those Maya, illusion etc. came into picture only when philosophers and scholars started interpreting the Upanishads according to their understanding. It's basically their own theory. No one knows whether it is true or not @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: So sensible you are @Rickross Ji So what should we focus on? Dharma right? And forget all these philosophical debates??

Comment: Yes of course .. philosophical debates are never good for spiritual persons.@SethuSrivatsaKoduru